# Saving the Xpath Underneath a mouse Cursor Or at the location of a click Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

so i am trying to make a selenium browser where i could save the xpaths of elements underneath the mouse cursor or the location of a click.

I have had a look around and have not found anything related to the topic, Nor have i found any such function to get me the Xpath Underneath or at a click.

This will allow me to manually save little selenium functions which could be exported and re ran.

Comment: Would love to know if anyone has a solution to this!

Comment: Been there, done that. It is full of pitfalls and lots of javascript. You need to add a click eventlistener to the document body, then calculate the xpath in js when the event is fired then store the results into localstorage or send via http. Basically you need to inject this script for each page load, so add selenium to a thread which checks page id changes and injects the script on demand.